# Numba jit decorator num_threads for parallelization KeyError: Unrecognized options: {'num_threads'}

Tags: numpy, optimization, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, numba

Given:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import multiprocessing
import sklearn
print(np.__version__,nb.__version__)# numpy: 1.23.5 numba: 0.56.4 

np.random.seed(0)
a=np.random.rand(int(6e+8)) # very large 1D numpy array
```

I would like to calculate norm of very large numpy 1D numpy array.
A typical alternative would be `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize(a.reshape(1,-1), norm="l2", axis=1)` with an execution time of `14.5 sec`.

For more efficient implementation, I thought `numba.jit()` decorator would be probably helpful.
To further optimize the function, I tried to use `num_threads` argument to specify the number of threads for possibly even  faster execution:

```
@nb.jit(nopython=True,nogil=True,parallel=True,fastmath=True,num_threads=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
def normalize_numba_optimized(array):
    sum_of_squares = 0.0

    # Calculate the sum of squares of the array elements.
    for elem in array:
        sum_of_squares += elem * elem

    # Calculate the norm of the array.
    norm = np.sqrt(sum_of_squares)

    # Divide the array by the norm.
    for i in nb.prange(array.size):
        array[i] /= norm

    return array
```

However, running `aNumba=normalize_numba_optimized(a)`, I get the following error:

```
KeyError                                  
Traceback (most recent call last)
KeyError: "Unrecognized options: {'num_threads'}. Known options are dict_keys(['_dbg_extend_lifetimes', '_dbg_optnone', '_nrt', 'boundscheck', 'debug', 'error_model', 'fastmath', 'forceinline', 'forceobj', 'inline', 'looplift', 'no_cfunc_wrapper', 'no_cpython_wrapper', 'no_rewrites', 'nogil', 'nopython', 'parallel', 'target_backend'])"
```

while it works fine without specifying `num_threads` in `@numba.jit()` decorator and takes `3.97 sec`.

Has it already deprecated to use `num_threads` as one of the arguments in `@numba.jit()` decorator? Or is there probably any workaround as an alternative for this purpose?

### UPDATE:

Thanks to @Rutger Kassies, I do the following workaround:

I first do `print(nb.get_num_threads())` to obtain the available number of cpu cores of my machine and then I can manipulate it by `nb.set_num_threads(multiprocessing.cpu_count())`.

Comment: Yes, the keyword is unavailable. How about `nb.set_num_threads(multiprocessing.cpu_count())`?

https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/threading-layer.html#example-of-limiting-the-number-of-threads

Comment: @RutgerKassies yes thanks! now I can obtain the number of the cores using `nb.get_num_threads()` and then manipulate it by `nb.set_num_threads(multiprocessing.cpu_count())` .

Comment: @RutgerKassies is there any way to ensure I do not get overhead, meaning that not assigning really large value? I thought about `nb.set_num_threads(8)` would be sufficiently a good choice.

Comment: *"To further optimize the function, I use the num_threads argument to specify the number of threads for probably faster execution"* Numba is smart enough to set the number of thread to an efficient value. Unless you have a good reason to do that, this is not a good idea. It reduce the flexibility of the application and its portability. For example, this can be tuned using `OMP_NUM_THREADS` with the OpenMP backend. Setting the number of threads manually in OpenMP can even decrease performance with some runtimes.

Comment: Note that computing `1 / norm` is more efficient than dividing many values. Divisions are slower than multiplications. Moreover, `parallel=True` can speed up the first loop too because this is a well known pattern, but it will not do it automatically.

Comment: @JérômeRichard so do you imply that I should do `array[i] *= ( 1 / norm )` in my `normalize_numba_optimized` function for better and more optimized implementation?

Comment: Yes. Though `fastmath=True` might already do such optimization (fastmath assume that there is no NaN nor inf in your code and the associativity does not matter too, and few things like this). By the way, such operation should not scale well since it should be memory-bound.